# Are constructors disjoint in Agda? (or how to disprove inj₁ x ≡ inj₂ y)

Tags: constructor, agda, theorem-proving, disjoint-union

I need one more lemma showing that `inj₁ x ≡ inj₂ y` is absurd as part of a larger theorem about disjoint union types (`⊎`) in Agda.

This result would follow directly from **the two constructors for `⊎`, namely `inj₁` and `inj₂`, being disjoint.** Is that the case in Agda? How do I prove it?

Here is the complete lemma:

```
open import Relation.Nullary
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Sum


lemma : ∀ {a b} {A : Set a} {B : Set b} {x : A} {y : B} → ¬ inj₁ x ≡ inj₂ y
lemma eq = ?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data type constructors are disjoint. I'd say it's a theorem in Agda's type-system meta-theory.

You can try to case the `eq` proof (`C-c C-c`), and Agda will find the contradiction:

```
lemma : ∀ {a b} {A : Set a} {B : Set b} {x : A} {y : B} → ¬ inj₁ x ≡ inj₂ y
lemma ()
```

This happily type-checks.

Comment: Haha, no way! I really ought to have tried that. Thanks.

Comment: You can also use large elimination to prove false with no primitive absurd patterns. The basic is that you can write a function that takes your `inj₁` to `⊤` and `inj₂` to `⊥`. You can then use `subst` with that function to "cast" a trivially obtainable value of type `⊤` to a `⊥`.